# aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1 comnand failed .

Tags: amazon-web-services

An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: User: arn:aws:iam::325699294512:user/s3-imports is not authorized to perform: ecr:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: *

Answer (score 1):

You have to add to your user :"s3-imports" at least read only access for ecr.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
        "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
        "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
        "ecr:ListImages",
        "ecr:DescribeImages",
        "ecr:BatchGetImage"
    ],
    "Resource": "*"
}]
}
```